# Refresh Button disable

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Currently I have a requirement to disable the functionality of refresh button in all browsers. I can do that for F5 button but for the refresh button I didn't get any idea. even i googled this. I  didn't get any ideas. Please help me in this. This requirement is needed for security purpose, because my application has URL change activities on some scenarios.

For f5 i am trying like this,

```
function checkKeyCode() 
{ 
switch (event.keyCode) 
{ 

case 116 : // 'F5' 
event.returnValue = false; 
event.keyCode = 0; 
window.status = "We have disabled F5"; 
break; 
}

}
```

Comment: You will not be able to disable the refresh button. Find another way to achieve your business objective.

Comment: One golden rule for design a web application is that you don't change the way the navigation of the web browser works.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do this, not without some kind of weird plugin you want the user to install.

The browser is a runtime environment that reads your HTML files and executes what are in them. So, as far as you can intercept keystrokes in the HTML document, you still won't be able to stop the browser from refreshing as that is a client-side action you have no control over.

The closest to a solution you will get is to use cookies or some Javascript to intercept the fact that the page has been refreshed, then you can deal with it in your web application.

Comment: Thanks firends.. I ll acecpt this.. i got a another way for that.. When changing the url i am checking some condition and if it is not there means i am showing the session failure page.. Anyhow thanks for ur valuable advice friends.....

Comment: Hi Nagarajan, no problem. Stack Overflow is all about sharing knowledge. I'm glad you had a solution.